# add style file selector in wordpress customizer

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm developing a WordPress theme and I'm trying to add an option in WordPress customizer to make the user able to choose between many styles files included in the theme, what I'm trying to do is quite simple, a select option that allow to the user to choose style 1-style 2- etc... the problem is that I didn't find any tutorial on how to do that, all what I have find is how to customize the colors and that's not what I'm looking for. can anyone help or at least gives me ideas on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

i have find this solution myself and it works preety fine

```
function stlye_selector( $wp_customize ) {
    $wp_customize->add_section(
        'stlye_files_selector',
        array(
            'title' => 'stlye files selector',
            'description' => 'you can set here your style file',
            'priority' => 35,
        )
    );
$wp_customize->add_setting(
    'colors',
    array(
        'default' => 'blue',
    )
);

$wp_customize->add_control(
    'colors',
    array(
        'type' => 'select',
        'label' => 'your style',
        'section' => 'stlye_files_selector',
        'choices' => array(
            'blue' => 'blue',
            'red' => 'red',
        ),
    )
);
}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'stlye_selector' );
```

and to use it just add this to ur template file

```
<?php $stat= get_theme_mod( 'colors','blue'); ?>
```

if no color is slected it will be on blue style